# variable type issue in carl bot tag programming

Tags: discord, dsl, variable-types

I am making a tag for Carl bot (Discord) in which it should sum up the numbers of an arrray, since I couldn't find how to implement an array I faced issue with this code returning 0+10+10 (in 1 to 3 situation). I don't know what good alternative of this code could be but I couldn't find any conversion functions, loop or array examples, maybe Carl bot doesn't support them at all so I need help with this:

```
{=(levels):{1}|{2}}
{=(total_minutes):0}
{all({1}<2|{2}>=2):{=(total_minutes):{total_minutes}+10}}
{all({1}<3|{2}>=3):{=(total_minutes):{total_minutes}+10}}
...
```

The amount of minutes will change with level, I read level range and function {all} will see if summing up is needed

Branches are not the issue here, I tried summing up with another variable as well but the result was the same. I tried looking for conversion, array and loop functions but couldn't find anything.